# Are there any results on the chromatic number of planar regular graphs not using the 4CC?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Are there any theorems regarding the chromatic number of planar regular graphs of degree 4 and 5 that do not rely on the 4CC? Please provide a reference if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Well, trivially any $n$-regular graph can be $(n+1)$-colored, so what kind of theorem were you expecting for the 4-regular case?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Five_Color_Theorem $\:$

Comment: @Henning I was looking for a better upper bound if available. I'm aware of the 5CC and the trivial case you mentioned. And by 4CC I mean the actual general proof of the 4CC. So proofs for special cases/subsets of planar graphs are still allowed if they provide an upper bound for the regular graph case in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Which meaning of [4CC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4CC) are you referring to? And how much effort is it to expand the acronym at least once?

Comment: 4CC = 4 Colour Theorem

Comment: I don't really get what you mean at all.  You say don't use the 4 color theorem, but then in the comment it seems like what you really mean is you want a BETTER bound than 4 colors.  If what you really want is a better bound than the 4 color theorem, you should say, "I am looking for a bound that is even better than the 4 color theorem" and not "I want a bound not using the 4 color theorem".  The second question can be answered by Henning and by Ricky as they did.  The first can not be answered by either.

Comment: I can see how it might be confusing. I'll try again. Basically, is there a result (perhaps obtained before the 4CC was proven) that uses different techniques to the 4CC to find a bound on the chromatic number specifically for regular planar graphs (or some superset of these graphs) that is better than the obvious n+1.

Comment: Ah, okay, that seems clear enough now.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

The book "Graphs and Digraphs", Fifth Edition, by Chartrand, Lesniak, and Zhang contains a section called "Bounds for the Chromatic Number".  Here are the two results that seem to best fit what you're asking for.  They don't use planarity at all.

Theorem

> For every graph $G$, $$\chi(G) \leq 1 + \Delta(G).$$

Theorem

> For every connected graph $G$ that is not an odd cycle or a complete
>   graph, $$\chi(G) \leq \Delta(G).$$

So, for a regular connected graph with vertex degree 4 (assuming it's not a $K_5$, and it's definitely not a cycle based on the degree), we know that it can be colored with at most 4 colors.  And, for one with vertex degree 5 (assuming it's not a $K_6$), it can be colored with at most 5 colors.  Of course, the second theorem could be extended to non-connected graphs so long as none of the components are odd cycles or complete graphs.